# How to assign value1 to value2 in post request?

Tags: php, html, xmlhttprequest, postman, http-post

How do you assign `value1` to `value2` in post request?

For example:

```
www.site.com/index.php?value1=10&value2=value1&value3=value2+1
```

How do you make `value2 = value1` in the URL?

Comment: Expressions aren't evaluated in URLs. You have to change the code that creates the URL in the first place.

Comment: There is no way to do this in the url?@Barmar

Comment: No. URLs are just literal text.

Comment: so i cant send a function through a url for example? @Barmar

Comment: You can send the source code of a function as a string, as long as it's not too long.

Comment: But there's no guarantee that the server can parse that source code. There's no standard language for sending functions over the network.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar

Comment: why postman is tagged ? is it postman related

Comment: Please add proper tag and specify what tool or library this question is focused at

Comment: any help with this problem please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70409247/a-problem-with-the-html-file-changes-its-format-when-uploaded-to-the-server @Barmar

Comment: any help with this problem please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70409247/a-problem-with-the-html-file-changes-its-format-when-uploaded-to-the-server @PDHide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL is just raw-text, so you need to either:

- Use `JavaScript` to get what `value1` is currently, then set `value2` to be same, with `jQuery` it's something like:

```
$("#myFormId").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);

  // Finds URL using form's action attribute.
  var url = $form.attr('action');

  // You may change this part.
  var value1 = $('#myFirstField').val();
  var value2 = value1;
  var data = {
    value1: value1,
    value2: value2,
  };

  // Sends the request.
  var listener = $.post(url, data);
  // Handles the response.
  listener.done(function(data) {
    console.log('success', data);
  });
  listener.fail(function() {
    console.log('failed');
  });
});
```

- Or, simply remove `value2` from URL, if it's always equal to `value1`, then use `PHP` to do set `value2` parameter (something like `$value2 = $value1;` or whatever your API to change URL-param needs).

Comment: How to use JavaScript to get what value1 is currently, then set value2 to be same ? @Top-Master

Comment: @Azaiter added an example.